# split array where there are big differences

Tags: python, arrays, split

I have an array which gives me a plot like this:

[image: this image plots the points in my array, and as you can see there are 6 clear zones where the total amount in y is different than the adjacent one.]
(this image plots the points in my array, and as you can see there are 6 clear zones where the total amount in y is different than the adjacent one.)

What I would like to do is split the array which gave me this plot in different subsets. What I am trying to achieve is count the lengths of this subarrays

Comment: Please share a small sample of array so that other developers can form a solution to split that subarray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple attempt, you can adjust this for your specific case:

```
def split_list(list, difference, min_size=None):
    i = 0
    accumulators = [[list[0]]]
    for i in range(1, len(list)):
        if abs(list[i-1] - list[i]) > difference:
            if min_size is not None and len(accumulators[-1]) < min_size:
                continue
            accumulators.append([list[i]])
        else:
            accumulators[-1].append(list[i])
        
    return accumulators

print(split_list(
    [1,2,3,4,5, 10000, 10001, 10002, 10003, 10005, 60, 64, 67, 100], 100, 4
))

# out: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [10000, 10001, 10002, 10003, 10005], [60, 64, 67, 100]]
```

Comment: Counting the size of the subarrays is trivial after that, or you could simply use an array of counters instead of accumulators to never create them in the first place.

Comment: Thank you very much, i think this will help me to solve the problem I got.

Comment: glad to help, if you could accept my answer (click the check mark next to it) that would help a lot.